# Air is all around us

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Air is all around us.

All around means *in every way* according to the dictionary. But this explanation doesn't make sense in above sentence, so I guess something maybe wrong here.

Does it mean something else here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that *all around* **can** mean "in every way".  In this sense, it can be an adjective:

> Jimmy's an **all-around** great guy.

This means he's great in every way.  It can also be used as an adverb:

> It's been a good day **all around**.

This means it's been a good day in every way.

---

However, that's not the meaning of *all around* in your sentence:

> Air is **all around** us.

Here, it means you're **surrounded** by air.  You can find air in pretty much every direction, except perhaps beneath your feet.  It's ahead of you, behind you, above you; it's around your head, around your hands, around your legs; it's *all around* you.

Comment: No. I'm referring to this one http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/all_2

Comment: @canoe Thank you for the link!  I edited my answer.